# Как не валидировать поле в одном методе контроллера

Tags: php, laravel, валидация, controller

Фреймворк: **Laravel 5.7.27** (PHP **7.2.10**)

Есть несколько методов в которых проходит валидация на сервере через явное обозначение класса запроса: `public function store(PostRequest $request)`

В файле `PostRequest.php` обозначаются правила валидации:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|min:10',
        'text' => 'required|min:10',
        'image' => 'required|file|image',
    ];
}
```

Во всех случаях нужна валидация картинки `image` по правилу `required`, но в одном методе не нужна, как мне ее предотвратить?

Comment: Получите массив и удалите ключ.

Comment: Перехватить запрос не получится, он направляется в этот контроллер и видит аргументом тип Request, он сразу же обращается к нему, чтобы отловить ошибки валидации

Comment: Если `rules` сразу в модели, то тогда вам доступен сам объект PostRequest. Проверьте что-нибудь у него. Я так понимаю у него `id` должен быть. В зависимости от наличия `id` возвращайте тот или иной массив правил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил костылем. `PostRequest.php`:

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required|min:10',
            'text' => 'required|min:10',
        ];
        if(!$this->request->has('id')) $rules['image'] = 'required|file|image|max:2048';
        return $rules;
    }
```

Если в `$request` нет `input[name=id]`, то в массив с правилами добавляем проверку изображения. Также можно было отправлять `input[type=hidden]` с названиями формы.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, правильнее всего будет создать для этого метода отдельный FormRequest и в нем задать правила валидации:

```
class MethodRequest extends PostRequest 
{
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();
        $rules['image'] = 'nullable|file|image';
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

И соответственно использовать его в контроллере:

```
public function method(MethodRequest $request)
```